# Mass and energy of radiation

Tags: energy, mass, atomic-physics, mass-energy, spectroscopy

We know that mass can be  converted to energy and vice versa. So does the mass of molecules or atoms change when they absorb a radiation and go to the higher energy state?

Comment: I'm suspecting yes, though it may not be practically measurable

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149744/.

Comment: Not a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149744, because that question asks about the mass of the electron itself, but the answers to that question also address the present question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. For example, when a hydrogen atom absorbs a photon and transitions from the $1s$ ground state to the $2p$ excited state, with 10.2 electron-volts more energy, its mass increases by $1.8\times 10^{-35}$ kilograms, or about one part in 100 million. This is just $\Delta m=\Delta E/c^2$.