# Does $E=mc^2$ apply to electron shells with different energies?

Tags: energy, mass, electrons, atomic-physics, mass-energy

Is this statement true: Each electron shell has a different energy level, with those shells closest to the nucleus being lower in energy than those farther from the nucleus. Mass of electron $= 9.10938356 \times 10^{-31}$ kilograms
so if electron energies vary based on the shell...
Then $E=mc^2$ is wrong? (right?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the mass of an electron change with its "energy state"?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149744/)

Comment: Hi David. This is an excellent question and perhaps surprisingly the answer is that the mass of the atom does change as the energy level of the electron changes. See the question I've linked as this discusses it in detail.

Answer (score -1):

My understanding is that the statement is broadly true. The energy states of electrons in atoms are described by solutions to the Schrödinger equation, the spatial distributions of which vary (you can see graphical representations of them on the internet if you google electron orbitals). Generally the solutions with higher energies have a wider spatial spread around the nucleus, which you can loosely interpret as meaning 'farther from'.

The mass of the electron that you quote is its 'rest mass', which means the mass you would measure if the electron is stationary compared with you.

When an electron gains additional kinetic energy (ie it is moving compared with you) its effective mass will increase. If an electron gains additional energy E, then its effective mass increases by a factor of E/c^2. Since the denominator is so large, the increase in mass is negligible at low speeds.

If that doesn't make sense, let me know what's unclear and I will try to clarify.

Best wishes