# Could a potential well be big and deep enough to cancel out the rest energy of a particle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mass, potential-energy

Here's an example of what I mean. The the ground state of an electron in an atom with $n$ protons is roughly equal to the ground state of an electron in a hydrogen atom, -13.598 eV, times $n^2$. Therefore, a big enough nucleus should make a deep enough potential well to completely cancel out the rest energy of the electron. The potential energy needed to cancel out the mass-energy of an electron is $-m_ec^2$. When you do the math, you get $\sqrt{\frac{-m_e c^2}{-13.598 \space eV}}=193.85$. This means an atom with 194 or more protons should be able to cancel out an electron's rest energy. I'm aware that there may be relativistic effects at play that might make this particular example impossible, but it's a good demonstration of what I mean nevertheless. Would relativistic effects always intervene so that a particle can never lose more potential energy than its rest energy?

Also, if this is possible, does it do anything weird?

Comment: energies can be negative. In hydrogen the energy of the ground state is -13.6eV…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose we consider a hydrogen atom. We start with an isolated proton and electron far apart from each other so the total mass is $m_p + m_e$. Now we bring the proton and electron together to form the hydrogen atom, and we can get $13.6$ eV of energy out e.g the energy could be emitted as a photon. This is what we mean when we say the binding energy is $13.6$ eV i.e. that energy of the bound system is $13.6$ eV less than the energy of the components. And since we have removed energy from the system the mass has been reduced to $m_p + m_e - 13.6~\textrm{eV}/c^2$. For more on this see [Does the mass of an electron change with its "energy state"?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/149744/does-the-mass-of-an-electron-change-with-its-energy-state)

But this $13.6$ eV binding energy is not associated with the electron i.e. we haven't reduced the mass of the electron. We have reduced the mass of the *bound system*. Nothing has happened to the electron or the proton.

In the example you describe relativistic effects would indeed come into play, but suppose we ignore these and consider a nucleus with a mass $m_N$ and a charge of $+194e$ then if we bind a single electron to the nucleus we would get a bound system with a mass $m_N + m_e - m_e = m_N$ i.e. the mass of the bound system is indeed reduced by the mass of the electron. But this doesn't mean the electron has been somehow cancelled out because the binding energy is a property of the whole system, not of the electron or the nucleus.

So to answer your last question, yes it is possible but sadly it doesn't result in anything weird.

It isn't relevant to your question, but when we include relativity we do indeed get weird effects. It is possible to solve the relativistic equation for a one electron atom (with a point nucleus) and we find that the binding energy starts decreasing for very high nuclear charges and at some point the electron cannot be bound. For a point nucleus this happens for $Z > 119$, though real nuclei are not points and the maximum atomic number is significantly higher than this.

Answer (score 1):

This is discussed in Itzykson & Zuber, QFT, p 27. The Schrödinger equation is not applicable and one should use the Dirac equation. I&Z be actually solve the squared Dirac equation. The result is that for the ground state no results are found for a single electron ion with $Z\gt 137 (1/\alpha)$. For a realistic, extended nucleus this limit goes up to above 180. In this limit the electron energy gies to zero, so the binding energy equals the rest mass. Both the kinetic and the potential energy likely diverge

From this point if view the answer is: yes, the potential energy can exceed rhe rest mass. However the total electron energy cannot become negative.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking that the [rest mass energy of particles](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html), in your example of the electron, can change.

[image: restmass]

> The length of this 4-vector is the rest energy of the particle. The invariance is associated with the fact that the rest mass is the same in any inertial frame of reference.

The $m_0$ mass of the electron is the same in all frames, an axiomatic assumption in the [standard model of particle physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model). When discussing quantum mechanical entities and high energy ones one has to use the algebra of the relativistic four vectors.

In nuclear reactions, part of the rest mass of **the sum** of the four vectors of the interacting nuclei can turn into energy, but this again has to follow relativistic kinematics and cannot be simplistically defined with the concepts of classical forces and potentials.