# Looking for a graph of the running of the electron mass

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mass, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization

Is there a graph somewhere showing how the electron mass changes with energy due to renormalization up to around the Planck scale - assuming that the pure standard model is always valid (thus no GUT, no Susy)?

Note: The question is about the running of the mass due to renormalization.

Comment: Mass is dimensionful. It is not meaningful to ask about its running.

Comment: This is a follow-up of question https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/805829/ which was about the low-energy running. Running of particle mass is an effect of renormalization. It was clarified by Feynman. See, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_mass .

Comment: there are answers here https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149744/ that state the mass of the electron does not change in the present standard model

Comment: The question is about renormalization, not about bizarre personal theories.